# Xcodeでデバッグコンソールで"cin"入力をしたいのですが…

Tags: xcode, c++

XcodeでC++を使っているのですが、
`cin >> n;`
のような入力をデバッグコンソールから行うことはできないのでしょうか？

現在mac初心者でXcodeの使い方がまだよくわかっておらず、本当に初歩的な質問で申し訳ないですが意外と調べてもヒットしなかったので、教えていただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: ひょっとして、coutに出力したものがデバッグコンソールに表示されるように、デバッグコンソールからcinに入力したいということですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。そういうことです！